# Unable to make my script stop printing wrong result

Tags: vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've created a script in vba using IE to fill in few inputs in a webpage in order to reach a new page to check for some items availability based on inputting some values in an inputbox.

To walk you through: what the script is currently doing:

1. Select `Buy Bricks` from landing page
2. Enter age `30` and country `United Kingdom` and then click on `submit` button
3. On the next page, enter the unique identification number for the Lego piece in the `Element/design` number box to populate result.

> My script can satisfy all the requirements stated above. However, when I try with three different numbers, as in `4219725`,`765467` and `230223` I can see that the one in the middle `765467` doesn't populate any result but It prints the result of it's earlier number.

All the three numbers have been used in a `for loop` within my script below.

***How can I make my script print nothing when there is no result instead of printing wrong result?***

[Site address](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/replacementparts)

My script so far: (could not kick out hardcoded delay)

```
Sub GetDetails()
    Const timeOut = 10
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, post As Object, inputNum As Variant
    Dim ageInput As Object, itm As Object, T As Date

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/replacementparts"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
        Dim event_onChange As Object
        Set event_onChange = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False

        Html.querySelectorAll(".arrow-list-info")(2).Click

        Do: Set ageInput = Html.querySelector("input[id*='How old']"): DoEvents: Loop While ageInput Is Nothing
        ageInput.innerText = 30
        Html.querySelector("[label='United Kingdom").Selected = True
        Html.querySelector("select").dispatchEvent event_onChange
        Html.querySelector("[ng-click='startFlow()'").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document

        For Each inputNum In [{4219725,765467,230223}]
            T = Timer
            Do: Set post = Html.querySelector("[placeholder='Element/design number']"): DoEvents: Loop While post Is Nothing
            post.ScrollIntoView
            post.Focus
            post.innerText = inputNum
            Html.querySelector("button[ng-click='searchItemNumber()']").Click

            'Can't kick out this hardcoded delay
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

            Do
                Set elem = Html.querySelector("div.list-item")
                If Timer - T > timeOut Then Exit Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While elem Is Nothing

            Set itm = Html.querySelector("h6.title")
            If Not itm Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print itm.innerText
            Else:
                Debug.Print "Found Nothing"
            End If
        Next inputNum
        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not a master of VBA. Do you need that `:` after `Else` in your condition where you are printing "Found Nothing"?

Comment: No, I don't need that but what I do need is write something in the spreadsheet when there is no result @Priyank Panchal. Thanks.

Comment: What does a manual input of the conflicting number produce?

Comment: `No results` @Luuklag.

Comment: Try to replace `If Not itm Is Nothing Then` with `If Not IsNull(itm) Then` check if it helps

Comment: Tried with you suggestion but still having the exact same behavior @Priyank Panchal.

Comment: Did you check what html element contains the no results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this needs tidying up but does it. I got rid of the explicit wait and added a wait for the spinner to disappear. For the no results section I look for an additional element to be present in the html when not found.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetDetails()
    Const timeOut = 10
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, post As Object, inputNum As Variant
    Dim ageInput As Object, itm As Object, t As Date

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/replacementparts"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document

        Dim event_onChange As Object
        Set event_onChange = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False

        html.querySelectorAll(".arrow-list-info")(2).Click

        Do: Set ageInput = html.querySelector("input[id*='How old']"): DoEvents: Loop While ageInput Is Nothing

        ageInput.innerText = 30
        html.querySelector("[label='United Kingdom']").Selected = True
        html.querySelector("select").dispatchEvent event_onChange
        html.querySelector("[ng-click='startFlow()']").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        For Each inputNum In [{4219725,765467,230223}]

                Do: Set post = .document.querySelector("[placeholder='Element/design number']"): DoEvents: Loop While post Is Nothing

                post.Focus
                post.innerText = inputNum
                html.querySelector("button[ng-click='searchItemNumber()']").Click

                Do
                Loop While .document.querySelectorAll(".basic-search-btn .icon-spinner-arrows").Length > 0

            t = Timer
            Do
                Set elem = html.querySelector("div.list-item")
                If Timer - t > timeOut Then Exit Do
                DoEvents
            Loop While elem Is Nothing

            Set elem = Nothing
            Set itm = html.querySelector("h6.title")

            If html.querySelectorAll(".alert.alert-info.margin-top.ng-hide").Length = 1 Then
                Debug.Print "Found nothing"
            Else
                Debug.Print itm.innerText
            End If
            Set itm = Nothing
        Next inputNum
        ie.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you help me understand how did you catch the spinner @QHarr? When you used this line `.querySelectorAll(".basic-search-btn .icon-spinner-arrows")`, you must have noticed the spinner's whereabouts. I tried with chrome dev tools but doesn't seem to find it out. Which tab within dev tools responsible for detecting that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With great difficulty. I had to screen grab. It is only present when whirring.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Usually pressing `F8` can stop that thing but the problem is I can't see any whirling.

Comment: I arranged the dev tools side by side with the (windows + arrow key) webpage whilst stepping through with f8. Clicked the button and screenshot. Probably easier to use screen recorder but screen grab worked.

Comment: It is likely instructions for the spinner are also held elsewhere.

Comment: Found that thing. Check out [the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4x430k7nii4hnkb/Untitled.jpg?dl=0). Pressing `F8` did the trick. I actually didn't notice that sign in the first place. Thanks.